# Haskell Conduit: is it possible to optionally have the result of a source?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have the following types built from [Data.Conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html):

```
type Footers = [(ByteString, ByteString)]

type DataAndConclusion = ConduitM () ByteString IO Footers
```

The idea of the second type being "produce a lot of ByteStrings, and *if* you can produce all of them, return a Footers". The condition is because conduits are governed by downstream functions, so the consumer of DataAndConclusion may have no need to consume all its items, and in that case the return wouldn't be reached. Which is precisely the behavior that I need. But *when* the end of the source is reached, I would like to have the produced Footers. This would be useful for example if the DataAndConclusions were incrementally computing an MD5 and such MD5 was only needed if the entire message was processed by the downstream (for example, downstream could be simply sending it through the network, but it doesn't make sense to finish computing and send the MD5 if the socket was closed before the last piece was sent by downstream).

So, basically I want to have something with this signature to consume a DataAndConclusions:

```
 type MySink = Sink ByteString IO ()

 mySink :: MySink 
 mySink = ... 

 difficultFunction :: ConduitM () a2 m r1 -> ConduitM a2 Void m r2 -> m (Maybe r1)
```

Question is, is there any way to implement "difficultFunction"? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be definitely a nice solution, but I wasn't able to construct it using `ConduitM` primitives. Something with signature

```
ConduitM i a m r1 -> ConduitM a o m r2 -> ConduitM i o m (Maybe r1, r2)
```

Looks like a primitive function with this signature would be a good addition for the *conduit* library.

Nevertheless, @danidiaz's suggestion about `StateT` lead me to the following generic solution that lifts the whole computation to `WriterT` internally in order to remember the output of the first conduit, if it's reached:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Void

difficultFunction :: (Monad m)
                  => ConduitM () a2 m r1 -> ConduitM a2 Void m r2
                  -> m (r2, Maybe r1)
difficultFunction l r = liftM (fmap getLast) $ runWriterT (l' $$ r')
  where
    l' = transPipe lift l >>= lift . tell . Last . Just
    r' = transPipe lift r
```

(untested!)

Comment: Well, this compiles, so it must certainly work. But I will have to do my homework and understand well all the pieces ...

Comment: I added an issue to Conduit: https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/issues/199 . Maybe is something that can make it to the library.

Comment: It's a good idea, I've just pushed a commit with this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

> This would be useful for example if the DataAndConclusions were
>   incrementally computing an MD5 and such MD5 was only needed if the
>   entire message was processed by the downstream

Instead of relying on the return value of the upstream conduit, in this case perhaps you could accumulate the ongoing MD5 computation in a `StateT` layer beneath `ConduitM`, and access it after running the conduit.

The other part of the puzzle is detecting that the producer has finished first. `Sink`s can detect upstream end-of-input in `await` calls. You could write a `Sink` that notifies you of upstream termination in its own result type, perhaps with a `Maybe`.

But what if you are given a `Sink` that doesn't already do that? We would need a function like `Sink i m r -> Sink i m (Maybe r)`. "Given a `Sink` that may halt early, return a new `Sink` that returns `Nothing` if upstream finishes first". But I don't know how to write that function.

**Edit:** This conduit sets an `IORef` to `True` when it detects upstream termination:

```
detectUpstreamClose :: IORef Bool ->  Conduit i IO i
detectUpstreamClose ref = conduit
  where
    conduit = do
        m <- await
        case m of
          Nothing -> liftIO (writeIORef ref True)
          Just i -> do
              yield i
              conduit
```

`detectUpstreamClose` could be inserted in a pipeline, and the `IORef` could be checked afterwards.

Comment: That's certainly a viable work-around. It would also be possible to use Data.Conduit.Internal and write something very similar to [fuseBoth](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v:fuseBoth)